# How to restore a SQL Backup .bak file on a different (new) server? SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, backup, restore

I remember myself restoring a db on linux side. I used mysql dump and before I could restore this backup on the other server I had to create a DB with the same name.

Now I am going to switch the server on windows side using SQL 2012. I am backupping many SQL DB's and call them for now db1.bak , db2.bak...

When I now want to restore them on the new server, do I need to create a "structure" first with the same DB names or can I simply restore my DB's with the restore command one by one.

Is there anything else I should prepare? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL Server database backup contains the structure and the data, so if you have run a full backup on one SQL Server 2012 server, you can restore this onto another SQL Server 2012 + server instance without having to create an empty database first.

Comment: thanks and if we are coming from SQL 2008  and migrate to 2012 ? Is there a difference?

Comment: Nope, going up versions using backups is fine (so long as you've tested your database on the new version that is, obviously) it's going backwards from 2012 to 2008 that causes problems, i.e. it doesn't let you restore it at all.